# node.js application-level rate limiting of 3rd party API calls

Tags: node.js, api, facebook-graph-api, rate-limiting

The app I am building makes heavy numbers of calls to the Facebook Graph API (but it could be any API with rate limit). For argument's sake let's say the limit is 600 requests per 10 minutes.

I'm using https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter to rate limit the individual threads, but what I need to do is rate limit all Facebook API calls at the macro app level, so that the app as whole does not exceed that limit.

I've really no idea how to accomplish that. I am fairly new to node and have no concept of what a solution for this would even look like.

It would be good to know if Facebook's rate limit is per app or per authenticated user. I'm assuming app, hence this problem.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe FB rate-limiting is based on either the account credentials or the source IP address of the incoming request.

Comment: This appears to be true... I will report back if I see otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you need to rate-limit access to a specific resource based on the aggregate of all of your requests, I'd create a separate http service to encapsulate and control all access to that resource.

Assuming you're using express and that your application runs on port 80, as in:

```
var express=require('express'),
    app=express();

app.get(route,function(req,res){
  ... do things here that need access to the FB Graph API
});

app.listen(80);
```

I'd add the following lines to your app.js, creating a new server running on port 8080:

```
var fbApiGatewayApp=express();

fbApiGatewayApp.get('/fb',function(req,res){
  ... provide access to FB Graph API here
});

fbApiGatewayApp.listen(8080);
```

where the routes you create for it control access to the FB API.

Refactor your original app so that it *only* calls routes on this new gateway service (via http.js) when it needs to submit a request to the FB API.

You can then rate-limit this new service to meet FB's requirements.

I'd also cause it to reject all requests that do not originate from your main app (which is running on localhost - 127.0.0.1) to restrict access from the outside world. (The same can be accomplished using a firewall.)

Comment: Thank you - I think it turns out that Fb limiting is per token so my session-specific limiting should be fine. But this is a good architecture for future reference.

Comment: I did come up with an alternative less elegant solution - my backend db knows how many reports are in progress, so at the start of every report, I divided the max limiter rate by the number of concurrent reports being generated.